Flutter - Using segmentedButton inside the drawer widget
The button is showing but it won't update it state or responde to clicking on it when it is inside the drawer.
It won't trigger the function i'm trying to call...
I use riverpod for the state management.
I wanted to have a segmented button with 3 parts to change the app theme (light, dark, system), and it worked with other buttons but not with segmentedButton.
Here is a git commit of the code...
https://github.com/dbl8005/meals/commit/918080298357b1570ed0f79e31ec515994e3529e
